# C# string interpolation pass value in

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

I have this read-only string in a class:

```
public static class XssProtectionConstants {
    /// <summary>
    /// {0} specifies the report url, including protocol
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly string Report = "1; report={0}";
}
```

I want to access it and pass in a value so that it now equals `"1; report=www.reportMyErrors.com"`

It is for this unit test assertion:

```
Assert.AreEqual(_policyValue, XssProtectionConstants.Report );
```

this throws:

```
Expected:<1; report=www.reportMyErrors.com>. Actual:<1; report={0}>. www.reportMyErrors.com
```

How can I update my assertion to make it equal `"1; report=www.reportMyErrors.com>"`?

Comment: Use string.Format. what is your code for changing your string? You're just appending it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Assert.AreEqual(_policyValue, string.Format(XssProtectionConstants.Report,"www.reportMyErrors.com" ) );
```